# Debug a flawed solution to a problem on independence and orthogonality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

From Exercise $24$ in Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682699

Let ${X}$ be a random variable taking values in ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the Gaussian distribution, in the sense that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$

(where ${|x|}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on ${{\bf R}^n})$, and let ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ be vectors in ${{\bf R}^n}$. Show that the random variables ${X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m}$ (with ${\cdot}$ denoting the Euclidean inner product) are jointly independent if and only if the ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ are pairwise orthogonal.

**Attempt**: For fixed Borel subsets $S_1, \dots, S_m \subset {\bf R}$, and $V = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_m \end{pmatrix} \in M_{m \times n}(\bf R)$, the unsigned r.v $\prod_{i=1}^m 1_{S_i}(X \cdot v_i)$ equals the unsigned r.v $1_{\prod_{i=1}^m S_i}(VX)$ (in the sense that two functions are equal), so their expectations should match:

$E\prod_{i=1}^m 1_{S_i}(X \cdot v_i) = E1_{\prod_{i=1}^m S_i}(VX)$.

By the change of variables formula, RHS $= \int_{{\bf R}^m} 1_{\prod_{i=1}^m S_i}(x)\ d\mu_{VX}(x) = \mu_{VX}(\prod_{i=1}^m S_i)$, and similarly by Fubini and Tonelli  LHS $= \prod_{i=1}^m E1_{S_i}(X \cdot v_i) = \prod_{i=1}^m \int_{\bf R} 1_{S_i}(x)\ \mu_{X \cdot v_i}(x) = \prod_{i=1}^m \mu_{X \cdot v_i}(S_i)$, where $\mu_{VX}, \mu_{X \cdot v_i}$ are the laws of the r.v $VX$ and $X \cdot v_i$, respectively, and thus we get independence.

This argument is clearly false as it completely ignores the orthogonality condition and the distribution of $X$, can someone points out where it went wrong, and possibly suggests a further direction without the use of things like covariance matrix? (the notion of variance is not even introduced at this point in the original context).

Comment: For the left-hand side, you switched the order of $E$ and $\prod_{i=1}^m$. How do you justify this?

Comment: @angryavian: By Fubini and Tonelli theorem, if ${X}$ and ${Y}$ are random variables taking values in ranges ${R, R'}$ respectively, then

$\displaystyle {\bf E} F(X) G(Y) = ({\bf E} F(X)) ({\bf E} G(Y))$

for any scalar functions ${F,G}$ on ${R,R'}$ respectively, provided that ${F(X)}$ and ${G(Y)}$ are either both unsigned, or both absolutely integrable.

Comment: I see you are quoting from Equation (8) in Tao's blog post. I believe the sentence should read "if $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables..."; notice in the next sentence he mentions "the converse is not true; (8) does not necessarily imply independence" [paraphrasing]. Going back to (8), it might be that the independence of $X$ and $Y$ was established in the previous paragraphs, but I agree it is written ambiguously.

Comment: @angryavian: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have any suggestion then on the correct direction to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the $v_i$ are nonzero to avoid some annoying edge cases.

---

Suppose $v_i$ are pairwise orthogonal. Then $m \ne n$. Let $u_i := v_i / \|v_i\|$. Extend $u_1, \ldots, u_m$ to an orthonormal basis $u_1, \ldots, u_m, \ldots, u_n$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U$ be the $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix with columns $u_1, \ldots, u_n$. Let $Y = U^\top X$. Then using rotational invariance of the standard Gaussian distribution, we have
\begin{align}
P(Y \in S) &= P(U^\top X \in S)
\\
&= \int_{\{x : U^\top x \in S\}} (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|x\|^2/2} \, dx
\\
&= \int_S (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|Uy\|^2/2} \, dy
& y=U^\top x
\\
&= \int_S (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|y\|^2/2} \, dy
& \|Uy\|^2 = \|y\|^2
\\
&= P(X \in S).
\end{align}

For measurable sets $S_1, \ldots, S_m \subseteq \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
&P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m \{X \cdot v_i \in S_i\}\right)
\\
&= P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m \{X \cdot u_i \in S_i / \|v_i\|\}\right)
\\
&= P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m \{Y_i \in S_i / \|v_i\|\}\right)
\\
&= \int_{\{y : y_i \in S_i / \|v_i\|\}} (2\pi)^{-n/2} e^{-\|y\|^2/2} \, dy
\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^m \left(\int_{S_i / \|v_i\|} (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-y_i^2/2} \, dy_i\right)
\cdot \prod_{i=m+1}^n \underbrace{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-y_i^2/2} \, dy_i\right)}_{=1}
\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^m P(Y_i \in S_i / \|v\|_i)
\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^m P(X \cdot u_i \in S_i / \|v\|_i)
\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^m P(X \cdot v_i \in S_i)
\end{align}

---

Sketch for the converse:

Suppose $X \cdot v_1$ and $X \cdot v_2$ are independent. Again let $u_i := v_i / \|v_i\|$. Using a similar rotation argument as above, you can show that $X \cdot u_i$ are each standard univariate Gaussian. Then
\begin{align}
&P(X \cdot v_1 \in S_1)P(X \cdot v_2 \in S_2)
\\
&= P(X \cdot u_1 \in S_1 / \|v_1\|)P(X \cdot u_2 \in S_2 / \|v_2\|)
\\
&= \left(\int_{S_1 / \|v_1\|} (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-y_1^2/2} \, dy_1\right)
\left(\int_{S_2 / \|v_2\|} (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-y_2^2/2} \, dy_2\right).
\tag{$*$}
%\\
%&= \iint_{(S_1 / \|v_1\|) \times (S_2 / \|v_2\|)} (2\pi)^{-1} e^{-(y_1^2+y_2^2)/2} \, dy_1 \, dy_2.
\end{align}
However, by a similar rotation argument as above, you can without loss of generality assume $u_1 = (1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and $u_2 = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0, \ldots, 0)$ for $\cos \theta = u_1 \cdot u_2$. Then,
\begin{align}
&P(\{X \cdot v_1 \in S_1\} \land \{X \cdot v_2 \in S_2\})
\\
&= P(\{X \cdot u_1 \in S_1 / \|v_1\|\} \land \{X \cdot u_2 \in S_2 / \|v_2\|\})
\\
&= \iint_{\{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 \in S_1 / \|v_1\|, x_1 \cos \theta + x_2 \sin \theta \in S_2 / \|v_2\|} (2\pi)^{-1} e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2)/2} \, dx_1 \, dx_2
\\
&= \int_{S_1 / \|v_1\|}
(2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-y_1^2/2}
\int_{S_2 / \|v_2\|}
(2\pi \sin^2 \theta)^{-1/2} e^{-((y_2 - y_1 \cos \theta)/\sin \theta)^2/2}
\, dy_2 \, dy_1
& (y_1 = x_1, y_2 = x_1 \cos \theta + x_2 \sin \theta)
\end{align}
This equals ($*$) above only when $\cos \theta = 0$, i.e. when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Does the split of the integral over product space into product of integrals follow from Fubini and Tonelli?